# Get Rack/Puma options in Rails configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, puma

I'm trying to determine, in my `config/environments/development.rb` file, whether Rails is configured to bind to a specific value when running `rails server`, and if so, what that value is, however I'm not easily able to see where/if this is available.

From looking through the source for the `rails server` command, I can see that the value provided to `--binding` is passed to the created `Rack::Server` subclass instance as the `:Host` option and subsequently to the `Rack::Handler::Puma` instance as part of the `:binds` option, but from there I'm unsure how to proceed.

I'm aware that I can parse the `ARGV` values to determine (literally) whether the `--binding` argument has been passed to `rails server`, but I'm treating that as a last resort.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but at the time `config/environments/development.rb`is read its probally already way to late in the server startup lifecycle to change the port. This sounds more like something that should be solved with foreman and a procfile. Rails should not really be concerned with configuring the server running it.

Comment: Thanks @max, I don't actually need to modify anything, what I wanted to do was set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options.protocol` properly based on whether the binding has the `ssl://` scheme